# Rでダイアモンド型を描きたい

Tags: r

以下の図のように、左に余白がないダイアモンドを描きたいのですが、どのようなコードを使えば書けるでしょうか？

[image: Rで描きたいダイアモンド型です。]

```
diamond <- function(max) {

    # Upper triangle
    space <- max - 1
    for (i in 0:(max - 1)) {
        for (j in 0:space) cat(" ")
        for (j in 0:i) cat("* ")
        cat("\n")
        space <- space - 1
    }

    # Lower triangle
    space = 1;
    for (i in (max - 1):1) {
        for (j in 0:space) cat(" ")
        for (j in 0:(i - 1)) cat("* ")
        cat("\n")
        space <- space + 1
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

画像にあるようなダイヤモンドを出力するならこれでどうですか。

```r
diamond <- function(n) {
  levels <- c(1:n, (n-1):1)
  for (i in levels) {
    cat(strrep(" ", n-i), strrep("*", 2*i-1), "\n", sep="")
  }
}

diamond(7)
```

Comment: できました。ありがとうございました。